# Spring Security OAuth2 Stale Access Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I currently have an application running as an OAuth2 client using Spring Security. Users are able to login with an OAuth2 provider (which works), at which point Spring Security takes the authorization code and exchanges it for an access token. This token can be accessed in the following way:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = oAuth2AuthorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(oAuth2RegistrationName, authentication.getName());
OAuth2AccessToken token = client.getAccessToken();
```

This token currently works for accessing protected resources with a resource server. However, an issue I am running into is that my application is keeping access tokens for too long, until they have become stale, and resource requests begin to fail. For example, once a user has authenticated, `OAuth2AccessToken token = client.getAccessToken()` will keep returning the same token forever (until application restart).

**How can I get rid of the access tokens and force the user to login again with OAuth2 flow? My OAuth2/OIDC identity provider does not support refresh tokens, so I need to force the user to login again.**

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` and/or `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient` annotated method arguments (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html#oauth2Client-registered-authorized-client))? Its job is to automatically manage tokens and detect/handle token expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a **custom filter** that check if token is expired

can you try this one approach and give me a feedback if it was helpful

```
@Component
public class Expired implements Filter {
  
  private final OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

  public Expired(OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext) {
    this.oAuth2ClientContext = oAuth2ClientContext;
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null && accessToken.isExpired()) {
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
      response.sendError(401);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
instead of return 401 code, you can force response to be redirected to login page.
Something like this:

```
if (accessToken != null && accessToken.isExpired()) {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("loginPage");
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not have the effect of causing the logged in user to re-login with OAuth2. It instead causes the request to be denied. This is because if you throw an AccessDeniedException when a user is already logged in, Spring Security does not ask them to log in again, but rather denies the request. Somehow the user needs to be logged out and then log in again.

Comment: i just updated my answer, check if this one will work in your case

Comment: I do not have a login page as Spring Security handles OAuth2 redirect. Do you know if there is any way to force spring security to redo OAuth2 flow?

Comment: according to documentation:  'The HttpServletRequest.logout() method can be used to log the current user out.

Typically this means that the SecurityContextHolder will be cleared out, the HttpSession will be invalidated, any "Remember Me" authentication will be cleaned up, etc.' after it you just customize your HttpServletResponse

Comment: So, I see how that allows me to log out the current client. But it does not allow me to log them back in within the same request. I need the following flow:

oauth2 logged in client makes an HTTP request -> their oauth2 access token is expired, so the server cannot proceed -> they are made to log in again through oauth2 flow -> spring security gets a new access token -> the request succeeds.

I think you are proposing:

oauth2 logged in client makes an HTTP request -> their oauth2 access token is expired, so the server cannot proceed -> they are logged out -> they make the request again

Comment: Yes their will be logged out and it mean that(user must to do log in, again through oAuth2) and so you will solve your problem, without refresh token.

Comment: and yes your right it not will be the same request it will be another one, i think its not a such big problem